# A limit problem

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, limits-and-convergence

Let $f$ be a bounded and continuous function, $0<a < 1$. $U(x,r)$ is the neighborhood of $x$ with diameter $r$.  Can we prove the following equation of two limits
$$ \lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \sup_{y,z \in U(x,r)} \frac{|f(y)-f(z)|}{|y-z|^a} = \lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \sup_{y,z \in U(x,r)} \frac{|f(y)-f(z)|}{r^a}$$
whenever they are finite or infinite?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This equality is not true. E.g., if $f(u)=u$, $x=0$, and $a=1$, then the left-hand side of the equality is $1$, whereas its right-hand side is $2$.

---

The OP has now switched the meaning of $r$ from radius to diameter. The equality is still not true. E.g., if $f(u)=|u|$, $x=0$, and $a=1$, then the left-hand side of the equality is $1$, whereas its right-hand side is $1/2$.

Comment: sorry, i have a typo. r is the diameter.